Nuxt 3 layout+page with height=100% doesn't scroll normally until a few seconds after page load
I'm working on a Nuxt 3 app with dvh units for height, and overflow-y-auto to keep certain layout elements stuck to top of bottom, and only scroll and transition the page content.
At first I was pleased with the result, but then I noticed that, in mobile, when you get you scroll down, neither the address bar nor the tabs bottom bar move out of the screen, losing so much screen real state that I could really use.
Example: https://buscamusicos-ui-nuxt-git-main-moluls-projects.vercel.app/es/musicos
So I'm trying to go for a different approach, not as clean, but I want to be able to reach full screen and show more content. This time I'm not using overflow-y-auto and I'm using fixed for the top and bottom elements
This is the second attempt (in this case, just html elements):
https://buscamusicos-ui-nuxt-git-main-moluls-projects.vercel.app/altLayout2
This layout does push address bar and tabs bottom bar out of the screen, but only after 3-4 seconds after page load, and that's really annoying. I wonder what might be causing a different scroll behavior depending on time, in such a simple page.
It's not hydration, as I put a flag to check when the page hydrates. But I can't figure out what else is happening there.
Any hint is greatly appreciated.
